How to get an attribute of a serializer class in DRF?
I have a serializer class CourseSerializer. A course can have a number of groups, lessons and etc.. A code for a serializer:
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lessons = MiniLessonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    lessons_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    students_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    groups_filled_percent = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    demand_course_percent = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_lessons_count(self, obj) -> int:
        return obj.lessons.count()

    def get_students_count(self, obj) -> int:
        amount = Subscription.objects.filter().count()
        return amount
    
    def get_groups_filled_percent(self, obj) -> int:
        counts = [group.users.count() for group in obj.groups.all()]
        return ((sum(counts) / len(counts)) / 30) * 100
     
    def get_demand_course_percent(self, obj) -> int:
        users = CustomUser.objects.all().count()
        students = Subscription.objects.filter().count()
        return (students / users) * 100

As you see, a serializer has calculated attributes like lessons_count, students_count ad etc..
The question is: how can I get one of these attributes in a serializer method, for example:
def get_demand_course_percent(self, obj) -> int:
    users = CustomUser.objects.all().count()
    return (self.students_count / users) * 100_

If I do like this explicitly, it gives an Attribute error that there's no such attribute in a serializer class

How about implementing the method as a call?
def get_demand_course_percent(self, obj) -> int:
    users = CustomUser.objects.all().count()
    return (self.get_students_count(obj=None) / users) * 100_

